# How to access a Hyper-V virtual machine remotely with Remote Desktop outside my network?

Tags: routes, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, hyper-v

Right now I have a physical server with Windows Server 2012 in which I am running a windows 8.1 virtual machine with Hyper-V Manager. How can I access this specific virtual machine without going through my physical server from Internet.
1. what should be the configuration for my Windows Server 2012?
2. What configuration my virtual machines should have.

Comment: To add more details. My Windows Server is not in Domain its a home PC. What if I have multiple VMs on my windows server and want to access through RDP from internet. How to perform the port forwarding ?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not perfect

Is that VM is on Domain?

If not at domain why dont you just use port forwarding in your router or firewall to that VM directly

Comment: You have an option to access all the VM's remotely but you cant just use the default remote desktop option available from Operating Systems. It is because of you cant forward single port for multiple machines at same time, so you forward seperate ports from router to 3389 as per your requirement and use tool "Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7" downloaded from Microsoft website.On that tool you has an option to configure port number check the setting to configure that while adding